# Mocha test will not resolve promise using Sinon stub

Tags: unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm using Mocha to test a method that has an asynchronous method inside of it. I'm stubbing that dependency with Sinon, and returning a resolved promise. But the promise is never resolved, or at least when the assertion is run it hasn't resolved yet.

Here is the method under test

```js
function identify(traits) {
  //THIS GETS CALLED SUCCESSFULLY
  userService.get().then(function(user){
    //CODE NEVER REACHES HERE

    userService.set(user).then(function(){
      //do something
    }, function(){
      //handle error
    });
  });
}
```

And here is the test

```js
it('should identify a valid email address', function(){
  var user =  { email: 'test@example.com' };
  var getUserStub = sinon.stub(userService, "get");
  var setUserStub = sinon.stub(userService, "set");
  var userReturn = { email: 'test@example.com', urls: ['http://some.url.com'] };

  getUserStub.returns(Promise.resolve(userReturn));

  //THE METHOD UNDER TEST
  identifyController.identify(user);

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(userService.get);  //WORKS FINE
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(userService.set);  //FAILS
  getUserStub.restore();
});
```

The assertion on userService.set fails, it says it was called 0 times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `userService` a global variable?

Comment: You may be hitting on something here. userService is a module but it is require'd in both the live code and the test file. Perhaps they're different instances?

Comment: We're using browserify for our modules, so I verified that userService is the same in both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem.

Promises are essentially asynchronous, but sinon calls are synchronous.

See this [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QypBYL?editors=001).

What happens:

1. You call `identifyController.identify(user);`

   - It will call `get`, which returns a promise, which is **asyncrhonous**.
2. The main thread of the program will still be running, so your both `sinon.assert.calledOnce` calls will happen in sequence, **synchronously**

By the time `get` resolves itself and calls `set`, because promises are non-blocking, the assertion will already have been executed, so it will fail.

So, you can do like this:

```
function identify(traits) {
  return userService.get().then(function(user){
    console.log('get');    
    userService.set(user).then(function(){
      console.log('set');
      //do something
    });
  });
}
```

And change this:

```
identify(user).then(function(){
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(myObj.get);  //WORKS FINE
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(myObj.set);  //WORKS FINE NOW
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I added the return statements and the catch block, but unfortunately no error is in the console.

Comment: I'm assuming `userService.get()` is a thenable, am I right?

Comment: I'm confused about your question. I'm stubbing that method, and making it return a resolved promise. So, then, it has to be, right?

Comment: Sorry, I should've ask "Are you using the [promisified version of sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised)?"

Comment: No sir, should I be?

Comment: I've never used sinon, so I don't know if `getUserStub.returns(Promise.resolve(userReturn));` works as we'd expect. Maybe you should give it a try, since there are no errors being thrown.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. As I've said, the first .then block never gets called (on the call to get()) so it never even got the point where it could call the set method. The whole problem lays in the fact that the call to get() never resolves with the stub's .return. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you add a `catch` to the outter promise, are you able to see any errors? If not, then probably the promise is stuck in pending state.

Comment: I added a .catch(function(e) { console.log(e); }) but it didn't output anything.

Comment: Now I got it. See the answer and this [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QypBYL)

Comment: Dude, right before you posted this I added the return statements and it worked! But you provided a very nice explanation as to WHY it worked. Thanks so much!!! Marking as accepted answer...

Comment: Actually, I realize that the inner return on the set method is not required, and actually causes the expect on the set call to fail. I'm not sure if that's happening with your codePen, but can you modify the answer accordingly? I could do it myself, but not sure what the proper etiquette is here.

Comment: Like this did you mean?

Comment: Yes, thanks. There is no need for a return there as identify will return the promise back to the test.